# Decoding gzipped http response that is inside json object

Tags: python, gzip

I am attemping to get data from an HTTP post using the following snippet:

```
import request

# Using @ to signify personal info
url = "@@@@@"

querystring = {"user":"@@@@@yahoo.com"}

headers = {
    'token': 1234,
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'host': "@@@",
    'connection': "Keep-Alive",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip",
    'content-length': "0",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers,     params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I get the following result (the ... is the rest of the 'data' string):

```
{'data': 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAO...T7R358EQT/u3/8D+8Rtv5/DwIA', 'error_code': 0, 'response_desc': 'SUCCESS'}
```

Unlike all other questions I have found on stackoverflow, the gzipped data of interest lives within a json response. The json object itself is not compressed. I have tried

```
zlib.decompress(response.json().get("data"),15 + 32)
```

But get the error

```
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not'str'
```

Am I going about handling the decoding correctly? I see plenty of documentation on decoding a gz file but this is just a string that is gz compressed.

---

Additional attempt: trying

```
zlib.decompress(response.json().get("data").encode(), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

Gives me the error:

```
incorrect header checkk
```

Comment: Try `zlib.decompress(response.json().get("data").encode(), 15 + 32)`

Comment: Hmm... I get an error: "incorrect header check". I feel confident that the data is valid gz since I can use an online decoder such as http://www.txtwizard.net/compression to get the correct decoded string.

Comment: Yes. Try `zlib.decompress(response.json().get("data").encode(), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)` The previous header was incorrect it seems.

Comment: Same "incorrect header check" :(

Comment: Is there a way you can share your compressed data? It would help with debugging.

Comment: Sure! https://pastebin.com/uYiz5dTH here it is

Comment: I tried. But it just doesn't seem possible. I keep getting the same incorrect  header check. Is it possible to get the entire response compressed and not just the data attribute?

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer's credit is to the authors of http://www.txtwizard.net/compression:

It turns out the string needed to be base64 decoded first before being decompressed with the format suggested by @coldspeed in the comments.

```
zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(response.json().get("data")), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string into a byte array first. This can be done two ways

```
bytes = bytes(your_string)
```

or

```
bytes = your_string.encode()
```